# If grammar in Microsoft Word fields

Tags: if-statement, field

I am trying to compare two summations like this

One is `Sum(Above)` the other is `Sum(Left)`.
If both are same it says `OK` or `Nah`.

[image]

But it gives `Nah` only.
What is wrong with this field codes ?

Thanks